# Custom Block on Checkout Page Sidebar

Tags: checkout, knockoutjs, magento-2.2.1

I want to add custom module's block on the checkout page in the sidebar below all the elements. 
How can I do so? 
It will be helpful if anyone can guide or provide correct steps or any sample code.